# Comparison and assign value via click button in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to assign a value in column like serial number via click button. I already a make one code but its without button. I want to add button also.

```
Option Base 1
Function Check()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim startCell As Range
    Dim firstNonEmptyCell As Range

    Set startCell = Range("G2")

    If VBA.IsEmpty(startCell.Value) Then
        MsgBox "No data in this column"
    Else
        Range("A2") = 1
        Range("A2").Select
        Selection.DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Date:=xlDay, _
        Step:=1, Stop:=400, Trend:=False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Do you want to number Col A for every cell that is filled in Col G?

Comment: Yes If in a column G is already data is there then its assign a value by serial in column A but I want to assign this value by click button. for button I got one link but how to merger button with this code please help me... http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-a-button-and-assign-a-macro-to-it-in-a-worksheet-HP010236676.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Insert a `Form` button via `Insert` in the `Developer` Toolbar.

   [image]
2. Paste the below code in a module and then right click on the button and click on `assign Macro`.
3. Select `Button1_Click` in the `Assign Macro` dialog box and you are done.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LRow As Long, i As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant worsheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Find Last Row in Col G which has data
        LRow = .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        If LRow = 1 Then
            MsgBox "No data in column G"
        Else
            For i = 2 To LRow
                .Range("A" & i).Value = i - 1
            Next i
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Comment: @Nitin If it helps you than accept the answers by clicking on the tick besides the answer